# Java: unable to "bruteforce" system of equation with for loop

Tags: java

I'm just getting started learning Java trying to solve some quick problem in the book. I've come to this problem where it asks to brute forcedly solves a system of equation.

> Numerous engineering and scientific applications require finding solutions to a set of equations. Ex: 8x + 7y = 38 and 3x - 5y = -1 have a solution x = 3, y = 2. Given integer coefficients of two linear equations with variables x and y, use brute force to find an integer solution for x and y in the range -10 to 10.

The input will be provided in the following format

```
8 7 38
3 -5 -1
```

So, I tried to parse the String to int array.

```
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input1[] = scnr.nextLine().split(" ");
        String input2[] = scnr.nextLine().split(" ");

        int xvar1 = Integer.parseInt(input1[0]);
        int yvar1 = Integer.parseInt(input1[1]);
        int zvar1 = Integer.parseInt(input1[2]);
        int xvar2 = Integer.parseInt(input2[0]);
        int yvar2 = Integer.parseInt(input2[1]);
        int zvar2 = Integer.parseInt(input2[2]);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        boolean havSolution = false;

        for (int i = -10; i < 11; i++) {
            for (int j = -10; j < 11; i++) {
                if ((xvar1 * i + yvar1 * j == zvar1) && (xvar2 * i + yvar2 * j == zvar2)) {
                    havSolution = true;
                    x = i;
                    y = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (havSolution) {
            System.out.println("x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Solution");
        }
        scnr.close();
```

My output: x = 1431655787, y = -10

The bound for both x and y should be [-10, 10], and here, my output is clearly out of bound.

Comment: `for (int j = -10; j < 11; i++)` <- The mistake is in this line. Can you see it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose)

```
for (int j = -10; j < 11; i++)
```

to

```
for (int j = -10; j < 11; j++)
```